# Docker service replicas are unreachable

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-stack

1. When i run below

   ```
   docker run --name foo -d -p 4000:1967 foo_service
   ```

   i am able to get response from my custom spring boot rest endpoint 
   with curl or from any browser (localhost:4000), so it is obvious that 
    **0.0.0.0:4000->1967/tcp**  port mapping works as expected.
2. But, when i run below

   ```
   docker stack deploy  -c docker-compose.yml foo_service
   ```

   i can not reach any of the containers and therefore no response from 
   localhost:4000 and also containers are immediately being restarted 
   after initial startup.

   I have run netstat command in all containers for both option 1 and 
   option 2. In option 2, i can see port 1967 is being listened but in 
   option 2, there are some random ports (i guess, this is normal, 
   since these ports publish themselves to 1967 to apply load-balance)

   Stack

   ```
   docker version 18.0
   java 1.8.181
   spring boot 2.1.1 (basic rest controller with one endpoint)
   ```

   Dockerfile

   ```
   FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
   VOLUME /tmp
   EXPOSE 1967
   ARG JAR_FILE
   COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
   ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
   ```

   docker-compose.yml

   ```
   version: "3"
   services:
     web:
       image: foouser/foorepo:foo
       deploy:
         replicas: 3
         resources:
           limits:
             cpus: "0.1"
             memory: 50M
         restart_policy:
           condition: on-failure
       ports:
         - "4000:1967"
       networks:
         - webnet
   networks:
     webnet:
   ```

   Does anyone know what is the problem here? What is the difference between each option?

Comment: In one you run foo_service, while the other you run foouser/foorepo:foo. You should also provide the logs and inspect output for any containers and services you want to debug.

Comment: Thank you for the log advice @BMitch, i have checked them and noticed in 2, the apps were being booted up very slow. Therefore i raised the resources and problem disappeared.